# XeLaTeX seems to perform no kerning, here. Why?

Tags: xetex, kerning

For some reason, XeTeX isn't providing any kerning no matter font I use.

The font I want to use is Goudy Old Style, which looks like this:

[image]

However, I also tried it with Garamond:

[image]

And here it is with Time New Roman:

[image]

I can't figure out what's wrong! Does it need to be enabled or something? I'm using Windows XP if that makes any difference.

Comment: We need a minimal example.  And there are many versions of Goudy Old Style, Garamond, and Times; specify which.

Comment: Also, what exactly are you expecting to see? What do you think it would look like if XeTeX was 'providing... kerning'?

Comment: Which TeX distribution (MikTeX?, TeXLive? something else?) do you use, and which vintage of Xe(la)TeX and -- I presume -- `fontspec`?

Answer (score 2):

The `kern` feature is on by default. Unless you have a badly made font with no kerning or poor kerning, or unless you interfere with it (we’d need a minimal example to determine that), you should see kerning.

Note that fonts from different foundries, though all re-creations of the same design, will differ in kerning and even in their glyphs. Here are the two versions of Goudy Old Style I have, for comparison; both handle the “Wo” better than in your image:

```
% compile with xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
% https://p22.com/family-Goudy_Oldstyle
\setmainfont{LTC Goudy Oldstyle Pro}[
  Contextuals=NoAlternate% use the longer descenders Goudy preferred
]

% https://www.theleagueofmoveabletype.com/sorts-mill-goudy
\newfontface\ofl{OFL Sorts Mill Goudy}[
  Scale=MatchUppercase% to make comparison easier
]
\begin{document}
Working towards

{\ofl Working towards}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of the above example]